# Is it true it's not natural to name folders (maybe just labeling in general?) something generic and or abstract?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

One of my native friends saw I had one of my folders named "私の物" and told me it sounded too weird. I also showed that my phone has a group of apps named like that and suggested I use something like その他 instead. Even only 物 alone bothered them and told me Japanese don't use abstract words. (For folders? I'm guessing labeling in general?)

I was told to be more specific but I told them I didn't have time yet or just plain don't want to organize them so I just put them under "stuff" indefinitely.

It's my own property so I want to name it what I want. I won't use it if it's incorrect but it is correct, right?.

Although my main concern that I don't want to change the unique way I think just because a native Japanese would never name it that. I do things that Japanese would never do or say like being too honest or direct about something (which my friend likes a lot).

TL;DR: Does labeling/naming something 私の物 sound awkward? I don't care if it sounds "not native" or I think the word I'm looking for is *unusual*.

But if it sounds like I'm just being an awkward foreigner and using awkward, clumsy words then I think I will change it in that case.

Comment: To clarify, Are we referring to folders in computer/smart phones (not the physical existence)? Also, you put just about anything (that you haven't classified properly) into that folder, am I reading right?

Comment: @Yosh Both physical and virtual folders. Yes, I just put anything that's not classified yet into that folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can use whatever name you want, but I would say 私の物 is not really "native". Personally, I have not seen a directory named `things` by English speakers, either. Have you? I feel most people like something a little bit more specific, like `docs`, `files`. In addition, `私の` has never been a natural naming convention in Japan. `My Document` on Windows is `マイドキュメント` in the Japanese version, and I think that was a reasonable choice.

If people need an unspecific directory name, they usually use `ファイル`, `ファイル置場`, `書類`, etc., without adding `私の`. (Of course I'm not saying this is a good naming convention.) If you share a computer with your family member, something like `太郎`, `太郎の`, `太郎のファイル` or `太郎の物` would be accepted.

If you want an explicit `etc` or `misc` folder, what I've seen (or used) are:

- `いろいろ`
- `その他`
- `雑`
- `未整理`
- `仮置き場`

Comment: I like to have fun with my naming. Here's a random example I found: https://goo.gl/zLDkSB I did actually have it in English before as "My stuff".

Comment: It's funny, when I saw 私の物 I immediately thought "I bet the folder is named 'My stuff' in English".  It's one of those times where the name looks obviously translated…

Comment: I feel "my stuff" would be okay in English, but 私の物 somehow feels closer to "things" to me... I don't know why.